# How do I fix this MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi there guys basically I have this query and I sort of get half of it but not all of it can someone please help me work it out?

[Query](http://gyazo.com/8e372fe56c9f9c5c28f77739bfa10e9c)

Thanks in advance! :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT username,first_name, last_name from members ORDER BY join_date DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Sachin I cant accept right now I have to wait a couple of minutes, I also have one last query to delete a single row.. But it isn't seeming to work.

Comment: @Ellie the one last query isn't in the question, though.

Comment: @hd Oops sorry but here is the question basically..  The new member Fredrick Williams needs to be deleted from the database. Write an SQL statement to delete all Fredrick’s details from the database.

Comment: @Ellie check my answer for the delete query.

Answer (score 1):

> List the username, first name, last name and date of joining of the five most recent members to register an account. List the results with the most recent registration first.

```
SELECT `username`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`join_date`
FROM `members`
ORDER BY `join_date` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

> @hd Oops sorry but here is the question basically.. The new member Fredrick Williams needs to be deleted from the database. Write an SQL statement to delete all Fredrick’s details from the database

```
DELETE FROM `members` WHERE `firstname` = 'Fredrick' AND `lastname` = 'Williams';
```

*Backup your database beforehand ;)*

Comment: Haha, and [@Sachin Gadagi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2581152/sachin-gadagi) is a few seconds faster than me :P

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USERNAME, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, JOINDATE
FROM MEMBERS
ORDER BY JOINDATE DESC
LIMIT 5
```